# How to calculate the length of a string array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I know how to calculate the length for a string array in c++ (`sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`), but I'm having a problem calculating the length of a string array if I pass an array through a method that's inside another class. Is there a reason why this happens?.

**main.cpp**

```
/* Allways returns 3 */

std::string arr[3];
int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

std::cout << length << std::endl;
```

**main.cpp but calling the method from a class**

```
/* Allways returns 0 */

Test* test = new Test();
std::string arr[3];
test->length(arr);
```

**Test.cpp**

```
void Test::length(std::string arr[]){
   int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   std::cout << length << std::endl;
}
```

I have passed in the array as a reference but It's not letting me do that, I have tried converting the array into a char array and passing in the value.

Comment: The array decays to a pointer when you pass it to another function. Subsequently, `sizeof(arr)` is evaluated as the size of a pointer (typically but not necessarily, 4 or 8 bytes), which is most likely not the full size of the original array. BTW, you're missing `[]` at the end of `void Test::length(std::string arr)`.

Comment: You probably didn't understand the difference between `std::string` and a `char[]` array. I have honestly no idea what you're asking about.

Comment: Your code does not compile, did you mean `void Test::length(std::string* arr){`.

Comment: would you know how I could fix it so as to always have it return the true value?

Comment: john, I fixed the typo, it's supposed to pass in an array in the method, I added the [ ] in the question

Comment: The size of an array is always fixed. It's really not clear what you question is. I'm also wondering whether you really want a string, and not an array of strings.

Comment: @PixelArcade As already said there is no way to have an array as a function parameter in C or C++. It's always a pointer (strings have nothing to do with this, any array would be the same). The C++ solution is to not use an array but use a vector instead. Then it's as simple as `vec.size()`

Comment: @PixelArcade https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Comment: Thanks, john, I'll try converting it to a vector, that should fix it. I wanted to do something different which it's why I was using an array, but either way thanks, that helped a lot.

Comment: std::array and std::vector ae what you should use in c++

Comment: Make your life simpler. Never use the built in array like `T[5]`, It's a holdover from C and has a lot of differences from the behavior of things like `std::vector` and `std::array` which are standard library objects. Instead of `std::string s[5]` use `std::array<std::string,5> s` and you will find you can pass values or references consistently. And `std::vectors` is really the best goto to replace C style arrays. Especially when you don't know how many you need (VLA).

Comment: Thanks, doug, gonna keep it in mind from now on when trying to go around arrays.